# V-for with nested objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, v-for

I have a v-for in a vue-bootstrap Card that I need to populate with the properties of an array of objects I am getting through api.

In the template:

```
<Card
   v-for="option in travelOptions"
   :key="option.id"
   :cardHeader="option.type | type"
   mode="Ford Mustang"
   :seats="option.trip_instance.remaining_capacity | seats"
   :date="option.trip_instance.departure_time | date"
   :time="option.trip_instance.departure_time | time"
   btnText="Select"
   @btnClicked="select()"
/>
```

The structure of the array of objects I am receiving is kind of like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "CARPOOL",
    "trip_instance": {
      "id": 23456,
      "departure_time": "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
      "remaining_capacity": 3,
      "trip": 138949,
      "vehicle": {
        "id": 1,
        "vehicle_type": {
          "category": "PERSONAL_CAR",
          "display_name": "Car Sharing"
        },
        "plate_number": "1234567890",
        "display_name": "Subaru",
        "color": "red",
        "capacity": 4
      }
    },
    "trip": {
      "id": 138949,
      "headsign": "hospital",
      "short_name": "C01",
      "direction": "0"
    },
    "pickup_point": {
      "stop": {
        "id": 36583,
        "lat": 45.1551513671875,
        "lon": 8.43579959869385,
        "stop_id": "id56757",
        "name": "il nome della fermata di pickup"
      },
      "arrival_time": "06:12:00",
      "departure_time": "06:12:00"
    },
    "dropoff_point": {
      "stop": {
        "id": 36583,
        "lat": 45.1551513671875,
        "lon": 8.43579959869385,
        "stop_id": "id909090",
        "name": "name dropOfff"
      },
      "arrival_time": "06:12:00",
      "departure_time": "06:12:00"
    },
    "reservation_type": {
      "mode": "CARPOOL"
    }
  }
]
```

`option.type` is displaying fine (it’s on the ‘first layer’ of the object)
`option.trip_instance.departure_time`, `option.trip_instance.remaining_capacity` are not, they’re nested inside the trip_instance object. And I will have to display few more properties of the other nested objects.

I dealt with nested objects when looping through arrays before (using v-for), and it worked fine, I could access the properties as I did in the template above. I thought the problem could be the lack of a unique id in the first layer of the object, so i created one and added to the objects of the array right before committing the action.
The new objects now have this outer structure:

```
[
    {
      id: 0
      type: 'CARPOOL',
      trip_instance: obj,
      trip: obj,
      pickup_point: obj,
      dropoff_point: obj,
      reservation_type: obj
    },
    {
      id: 1
      type: 'RENTAL',
      trip_instance: obj,
      trip: obj,
      pickup_point: obj,
      dropoff_point: obj,
      reservation_type: obj
    }
]
```

It didn’t solve the issue.
I read about creating nested v-for but it doesn't work for me. Also I am dealing with just one component (the Card), not with `ul` and nested `li`, as most of the examples I found offering this solution. I tried though, I created divs wrapping the card, one for each nested object.
Something like

```
<div
  v-for="option in travelOptions"
  :key="option.id"
>
  <div
    v-for="(trip, index) in travelOptions.trip_instance"
    :key="index"
  >
    <div
      v-for="(vehicle, index) in travelOptions.vehicle"
      :key="index"
    >
      <Card
        :type="option.type"
        :time="trip.departure_time"
        :seats="trip.remaining_capacity"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work, the whole Card doesn't show on the screen, and from the editor (VS Code) I can see the v-for is not 'taking' the dot notation.
I saw many questions regarding this issue but none helped me.
Can somebody help?
Thanks
x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I thought I read the data carefully, but in fact I didn't.

I would say there's no issue in displaying properties of nested objects with v-for, just it's crucial we know exactly what we're trying to display in every loop.

In my case I didn't notice that the object properties were not always the same (for example `trip_instance` wasn't a property of all the objects in the array, this was breaking the loop).

So, hoping to help someone, if you run into issues with v-for or iteration in general, **make sure you know exactly the data structure** you're working with.
Hope I got it too, once for all.

Thanks @djiss for your time and trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, propertyName, value) method:

```js
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
// interchangeably 
this.$set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

More information [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: I get you. I am getting the array from the store using mapGetters (first time I am making use of the helpers) and using it straight away without 'passing through' data(). So, following your advice, I created an empty array ```options: []``` in data() and on mounted I assigned travelOptions (the array got from the store) to it. 
Then, I used options in the v-for instead of travelOptions.

(Is this a better way of using mapGetters?)

Anyway this didn't solve the original issue.
The data of the nested objects are still not displaying in the Card.

Comment: Can you share the assignment code on mounted please?

Comment: ```data () {
    return {
      options: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('helpers', ['travelOptions'])
  },
  async mounted () {
    await this.getData()
  },
methods: {
    getData () {
      console.log('travel options in Home page: ', this.travelOptions)
      this.options = this.travelOptions
    }
  }```

Comment: Anyway it wasn't in data() but it's a computed property, so its changes are still detected. Still struggling though. Can't understand why...